# How to have Firefox not detected by bot with Selenium

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, firefox

I use Selenium in java to load a profile on Firefox (and execute a scenario after) with the following code:

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", "C:\\Programmes\\Maven\\geckodriver.exe");
FirefoxProfile fprofile = new ProfilesIni().getProfile("default-release-1");
FirefoxOptions option = new FirefoxOptions();
option.setProfile(fprofile);
WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver(option);
```

The problem I have, when I launch my scenario, is that the Javascript browser variable `navigator.webdriver` (to signal use of Selenium) is true.

I wish that the use of Selenium will be not detectable in the browser.

I find a lot of answers regarding Chrome, but none for Firefox (with the loading of a Firefox profile).

An idea ?

Comment: ...why?  It looks like Firefox is doing the right thing.